# Convert Object to Short

Tags: java, object, type-conversion, classcastexception

i want to convert Object to Short. my code is like this :

```
List<Batch> lsMaxBatch = em.createNativeQuery(sqlMaxBatch).getResultList();
Iterator iter = lsMaxBatch.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Short batchId = Short.valueOf(iter.next() + "");
    ls.add(batchId);
}
```

**is it okay?**

because if i doing convert like this :

```
Short batchId = (Short) iter.next();
```

i get an error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Short
```

thanks

Comment: You are trying to cast an array of Object (`Object[]`) to a Short. No it is not okay. You must cast to `Object[]`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, why would an object have an equivalent representation as a short?

Comment: because i only queries 1 column. and the type of column is short

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untyped queries like these return a `List<Object[]>`. The exception message hints at this: `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast...`.

To fix your code:

```
List<Object[]> lsMaxBatch = em.createNativeQuery(sqlMaxBatch).getResultList();
Iterator<Object[]> iter = lsMaxBatch.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object[] row = iter.next();
    Short batchId = (Short) row[0];
    ls.add(batchId);
}
```

Yes, getting a `List<Object[]>` sucks. To improve this, use one of the [`EntityManager` query creation methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#method_summary) which returns a `TypedQuery<T>`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to cast to `Number` and then get the `shortValue()`?

Comment: Possibly; I haven't considered/tried that. I just go straight for the `TypedQuery` solution whenever possible.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Well, that could also hide bugs, though. Let's say it's an `Integer` with a value of 365. You probably don't want the overflow wrapping, you want an exception (because the fact that you expected a short but got an int probably indicates a bug).

Comment: @yshavit I can't really tell why the OP wants a Short. All I can tell is that, depending on the actual SQLStatement and the JDBC driver, the return type can be different (could be a Long, an Integer, a Double, a BigInteger, etc...). Casting to Number and then getting the shortValue is one way to avoid CCE and having a shortValue. Using an Integer or a Long may be a better fit; I don't have enough context to test that.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Sure, and that's fair enough. I was just pointing out that while it helps you avoid a CCE, it could also mask whatever would have caused the CCE in the first place. Double-edged sword, but imho an exception is much easier to track down than a subtle "we masked an error, and a dozen classes later ran into problems" bug.

Comment: becase the result of the query is only 1 column, and the type short. and i have to make nativequery because i cant convert my SQL query itu HQL.

Comment: @DiazPradiananto that's fine. The code in my answer should work for you.

Comment: @DiazPradiananto the same `ClassCastException`? You should really try stepping through the code with a debugger to see what sort of object you are _actually_ getting back in the `List`.

Comment: my bad. when i see the HQL on the production server, is different with my HQL on development. problom solved, thanks all